objdump `--adjust-vma` destroys debug info
When using the --adjust-vma option of objdump all the functions get squashed together, as if there is no debug information about where each function starts.
I'll demonstrate with the following simple C file (a.c):
void func(void)
{
}

int main()
{
}

Compile it using gcc -g a.c
Now without the --adjust-vma I get plenty of information :
$ objdump -d a.out
Disassembly of section .text:

0000000000001040 <_start>:
----- Many other functions which I cut off -------
0000000000001129 <func>:
    1129:   f3 0f 1e fa             endbr64 
    112d:   55                      push   %rbp
    112e:   48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
    1131:   90                      nop
    1132:   5d                      pop    %rbp
    1133:   c3                      ret    

0000000000001134 <main>:
    1134:   f3 0f 1e fa             endbr64 
    1138:   55                      push   %rbp
    1139:   48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
    113c:   b8 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%eax
    1141:   5d                      pop    %rbp
    1142:   c3                      ret    

But with --adjust-vma I get the following:
$ objdump -d a.out --adjust-vma=0x100000
Disassembly of section .text:

0000000001001040 <main+0xffff0c>:
-------- No function markers, just a lot of instructions one after the other -------
# AM: That's the original `func`
 1001129:   f3 0f 1e fa             endbr64 
 100112d:   55                      push   %rbp
 100112e:   48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
 1001131:   90                      nop
 1001132:   5d                      pop    %rbp
 1001133:   c3                      ret    
# AM: That's the original `main`
 1001134:   f3 0f 1e fa             endbr64 
 1001138:   55                      push   %rbp
 1001139:   48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
 100113c:   b8 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%eax
 1001141:   5d                      pop    %rbp
 1001142:   c3                      ret    

Any idea why this happens?

The manual for objdump says this about the --adjust-vma option

When dumping information, first add offset to all the section addresses. This is useful if the section addresses do not correspond to the symbol table, which can happen when putting sections at particular addresses when using a format which can not represent section addresses, such as a.out.

A case where I would use this if I were packing code into a boot rom that I then was going to copy into ram and execute[1]. To make sense of the code that is stored in the rom, one wants to ignore the addresses as they are in the rom and consider what the addresses will be once it is copied into ram. The debug information reflects the code at the ram locations, not the copy being stored in the rom. The --adjust-vma option allows you to add the constant that is the difference between the rom and ram addresses,
Put another way, the --adjust-vma doesn't adjust debug information, just the addresses of the code.
[1] Code typically executes much faster from ram than rom, so if the code doesn't fit in the cpu cache it can be worth the extra time to copy code from rom to ram.

Do you maybe know of a way to make objdump just add the adjustments to all addresses, after getting the relevant data from the original address? For the case of an aslr-randomized process, or a kernel which relocates itself, this might be useful
